# TLS handshake issue connecting to docker registry in OKD

Tags: ssl-certificate, containers, openshift, docker-registry, okd

I am trying to setup my own OKD (v3.10) setup with one master and 2 workers. I went with the default registry installation. pods and services for the registry and routes came up fine. 
registry pod got created on the master node. All nodes are based on Centos7.

Now when I try to connect to the registry using `docker login` with the endpoint `docker-registry.default.svc:5000`, I am able to login only from the master node, but not from the worker nodes failing with the below message:

`Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry.default.svc:5000/v1/users/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

Registry container has the following log:

`1120 10:40:57.796470       1 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 11.121.8.192:48200: EOF`

This is just a test setup and not having any traffic to the registry now. While this seems to be a certificate issue, not able to figure out from the docs where to look further to troubleshoot.

Any insights ??

Comment: Out of desperation, I went ahead and scaled my docker-registry service replicas from 1 to 3 as indicated in one of redhat thread (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4358311), but did not help in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure docker to use it as insecure and restart the daemon.

`--insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16` in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arockiasmy for your reply. I tried setting the above in my /etc/sysconfig/docker file in all 3 nodes and did restart the docker service. I can see that the docker process is running with the insecure-registry option. But now, I am getting the error `Error response from daemon: Get http://docker-registry.default.svc:5000/v1/users/: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"`

Seems like registry is still responding as https.

Comment: Hi @SudhakarGariganti, Can you revert back the changes and add the Openshift self signer to your trusted CA list.

Comment: You will need to copy the Openshift CA from first node/master `/etc/origin/master/ca.crt` to other nodes `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` directory and run `update-ca-trust extract`. This will add the Openshift CA as trusted one. Then, docker should work (maybe restart needed).

Comment: Yea Arockiasmy, tried this already after stumbling across https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/install_config/registry/securing_and_exposing_registry.html . Still I have the same weird problem.

Comment: I then scaled down my docker-registry replicas back to 1, the pod on one of the worker remained and now I am able to login from this worker. Now it seems to be network issue to me. I have tried deploying the Openshift cluster with Calico as the network plugin, let me try recreating again with the default OVS CNIs.

Really appreciate your help  :) . Will keep you posted here, if I make progress

Comment: Did you try `curl -v -I https://docker-registry.default.svc:5000/v1/users/`? Can you please post the output. If it comes fine, then it should work. Hopefully, you specified the right network settings while setting up the cluster. So that routing will be proper to get a return.

Comment: Tried the above curl. Find the output snapshot here: 
https://imgur.com/1D2xypC

Comment: Looks like it needs more troubleshooting.

Comment: I have recreated my test cluster with similar underlying network as previous setup but skipped calico, just used the default CNI of origin. I can now login to the internal registry from all nodes. Cluster creation and scaling up are working fine now. Will try out with Calico in near future again and check.
Thanks a lot Arockiasmy for keeping me motivated here. :) Cheers !